# Nuxt 3 dynamic route not work on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

Nuxt 3 dynamic route is not working on staging properly , when i refresh the page on staging it redirect user to the home page.

In Nuxt 3 I have added the the dynamic route like this - "pages/test/[id].vue".
On deployed site when i reload the page with route "test/123" it redirects user to home page .
It's working fine on local but didn't work on staging.
I am new to nuxt3 please suggest any solution.

Comment: are you using supabase or something else? a package could make the redirect to /

Comment: @Flash No , i am not using any package, i am trying to reload the page , but it redirects me back to the home page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community, no code needed , i just added the index file in this route /pages/test/[id].vue